# Query to filter records based on input and precedence and if it does not match, pull the null value record

Tags: sql, oracle

Myrequirement is to write a query to display descrip, op based on the input parameters. In the setup Test2,  itm takes precedence over pm and that takes precedence over pf. If none matches, the null value setup would be the default.

I have a table Test1

```
GRP                  OP                  
----- --------------------
GRP1                 A                   
GRP1                 B                   
GRP1                 C
```

Table Test2

```
OP            ITM                  PM                   PF                         CUST DESCRIP             
------ -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- --------------------
A                                                                                   123 AB                  
C                                                                                   123 BC                  
B             I1                                                                    123 CD                  
B             I2                                                                    123 DE                  
B                                  PM1                                              123 EF                  
B                                                       PF1                         123 FG                  
B                                                                                   123 FGH
```

My Input parameters are test1.grp, test2.pm, test2.itm, test.pf

If my Input is GRP=GRP1, Itm=I1, PM=PM1, PF=PF1, my output should be

```
op   descrip
A     AB  
C     BC  
B     CD   (because itm takes precedence over others)
```

If my input is GRP=GRP1, Itm=I3, PM=PM1, PF=PF1, my output should be

```
op   descrip  
A     AB  
C     BC  
B     EF   (because itm I3 does not exist, so next precedence is pm)
```

If my input is GRP=GRP1, Itm=I3, PM=PM2, PF=PF2, my output should be

```
op   descrip  
A     AB  
C     BC  
B     FGH   (because the three conditions do not match, so null is the generic setup)
```

Appreciate if you can help with this as I am stuck comparing multiple records in precedence order.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write a query for my requirement.

```
`select coalesce(itmd,pmd,pfd,nulld), op from ( select a.op,
max(decode( itm,'I3' , descrip)) itmd,
max(decode( pm,'PM2' , descrip)) pmd,
max(decode( pf,'PF2' , descrip)) pfd,
max(decode(itm,null,decode(pm,null,decode(pf,null,descrip)))) nulld
  from test1 a, test2 b where a.grp='GRP1' and a.op=b.op
  group by a.op);`
```

Thanks